# How do you generate stacked fonts in blender?

Tags: text-object

There are certain Indian languages like Malayalam where there are stacked characters. The letters un-stacks itself and the individual letters stay nearby. I am using Blender 2.8 on an Ubuntu Machine. In the Libre office, the font appears correctly. However, in Blender, it does not. 
Any help on this, much appreciated.

To describe more...
"ട്ട " - This is the letter. It is actually formed by using the letter "ട" two times. In the Libre office, it appears properly like this. But when you add the letter in Blender it appears like this "ട് ട". I was able to recreate this by having a space between the two letters. If it is not there, the letter immediately forms the first stacked letter. In Ubuntu, I am using "Swanalekha", the language setting where you can type Malayalam by transliteration.

[image: This letter appears as below.]

However, it should be appearing like this.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to provide ant image reference or screenshot? It's hard to imagine what exactly you want and how that can be resolve in Blender

Comment: I just added more information. Kindly have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Ahh... It might be the **Font Ligature** issue, Blender might not be able to enable the functionality of the ligature.

Comment: Possible workaround: Use an application that displays them correctly export it to SVG or PDF if unavailable, convert to path in Inkscape and import as SVG

Comment: Thank you all so much for the replies. (I am an absolute beginner here, I do not know how to mark as useful or so. I guess I do not have the privilege now.)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - I tried this and it worked.